# Get the last non null value of a table column

Tags: sql, mariadb

Below is my table and from column B I want to get the value 3 in results.

| A | B |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | 1 |
| 2 | Null |
| 3 | 2 |
| 4 | Null |
| 5 | 3 |
| 6 | Null |
| 7 | Null |
| 8 | Null |

Case not working: it should return 10

| A | B |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | 1 |
| 2 | Null |
| 3 | 2 |
| 4 | Null |
| 5 | 3 |
| 6 | Null |
| 7 | Null |
| 8 | 10 |

Comment: Define the "last". Last by A, last by B or what?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a `LIMIT` query:

```sql
SELECT *
FROM yourTable
WHERE B IS NOT NULL
ORDER BY A DESC
LIMIT 1;
```

Comment: When i have case where Last column is not null like last is having value 10. this case is not working. I updated question where its not working

Comment: My query should be working for your added test case.

Comment: yeah I want to add the value by one so how i can do it i means 10 +1 = 11

Answer (score 1):

Do you want to get the value '3' because it is the largest in 'B' column?

If so, you can run the following query:

```
SELECT *
FROM Table
WHERE B IS NOT NULL
ORDER BY B DESC
LIMIT 1;
```

Answer (score 0):

There is not much to go on in the question. However, assuming that you can order by the col A, the answer would be

```
SELECT * from table
where B is not NULL
Order by A DESC
Limit 1
```

If A is numeric, then the order by works fine and you get all 3 non null values from column B. Then Order by descending + limit 1 will ensure you get last value of B

Answer (score 0):

You already received really good answers that should help you. I just want to add a futher propose that works fine if both A and B are numeric and they are always sorted like in your example, meaning the highest b entry always has the highest a value.

```
SELECT MAX(b) FROM tableB
WHERE b IS NOT NULL
HAVING MAX(a);
```